# Customizing a text field across a set of html files

Tags: html, chm

I am building a `.chm` file using a set of HTML files. Each html has a company name in its text. My problem is this company name needs to be changed for each of our clients. Rather than changing all of the HTML files, is there a way to keep it as a shared variable (Maybe in a `.css` file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace content inside an html element say `<span>` using `content` [property](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html) of css.

**html**

```
<span class="company-name">
   YourCompanyName
</span>
```

**css**

```
.company-name{font-size: 0}

.company-name:after{
      content: "New Company Name";
      font-size: 14px;
 }​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FwKW7/

There are some quirks in it. IE <=8  have limited [support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for this property and you check out more about it after checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300887/which-css-versions-are-supported-in-chm-files) on stack overflow.

Alternatively, you can also check-out this answer for replacing text using css [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212879/how-to-use-css-to-replace-or-change-text). But it requires an extra `div`, which is un-necessary.

***Edits**
 * updated css

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me. (I think the dash within "company-name" should be removed). When I try this I got "YourCompanyName" as the output. (i HAVE ie9 installed)

Comment: ya.. i'll update my answer. there will a dash. Yes!! sorry about that.

Comment: just check it again.. with my new answer and can u let me know if it works.

Comment: great... now if you mark this answer as correct it will be helpful for other too... :) and will save some of their time. regards

Comment: Yes I would like to do that. But could not find a place to do so. The left hand side up/down arrows to say "This answer is useful" is not allowed for me because I do not have enough reputations. Is there any other way to do it ?