# SVG Graphics in CHM (Html Help Workshop)

Tags: svg, chm, html-help-workshop

Im trying to use SVG-Graphics in a CHM-File. The CHM is created by HTML Help Worshop. Unfortunately the svg files dont show in my compiled chm... (Everything works fine in Html)

I already added my SVG to the Files section of my hhp. But still nothing.

Has anyone succeeded in using SVG Files in CHM created with Html Help Workshop?

Any Help is really appreciated!

Regards
Christian

(This topic is only related to SVG. Bitmaps work just fine...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML Help Viewer renders topics in the IE 7 standards mode for compatibility reasons (see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356168/113116) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/113116)), and IE doesn't support SVG until v. 9.

Possible solutions:

- [Change the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613025/113116) to make HTML Help Viewer use the IE 9 mode.
- Use some [JavaScript SVG libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1427051/113116) to render SVG. (Didn't try it though; just an idea.)

Comment: Works like a charm!

Thanks for your explanation of the problem and links to the solution.

:)